# How do I perform an AND search in Lucene.net when multiple words are used in a search?

Tags: c#, search, lucene, lucene.net

I am playing around with Lucene.net to try and get a handle of how to implement it in my application.

I have the following code

```
            .....
            // Add 2 documents
            var doc1 = new Document();
            var doc2 = new Document();

            doc1.Add(new Field("id", "doc1", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
            doc1.Add(new Field("content", "This is my first document", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
            doc2.Add(new Field("id", "doc2", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
            doc2.Add(new Field("content", "The big red fox jumped", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));

            writer.AddDocument(doc1);
            writer.AddDocument(doc2);

            writer.Optimize();
            writer.Close();

            // Search for doc2
            var parser = new QueryParser(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_29, "content", new StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_29));
            var query = parser.Parse("big abcdefg test1234");
            var searcher = new IndexSearcher(indexDirectory, true);
            var hits = searcher.Search(query);

            Assert.AreEqual(1, hits.Length());

            var document = hits.Doc(0);

            Assert.AreEqual("doc2", document.Get("id"));
            Assert.AreEqual("The big red fox jumped", document.Get("content"));
```

This test passes, which dismays me a bit.  I assume this means that Lucene.Net uses OR for searches between terms and not an AND, but I can't find any information on how to actually perform an AND search.

The end result I am going for is if someone searches for "Matthew Anderson" I don't want it to bring up documents that refer to "Matthew Doe" , as that isn't relevant in any way, shape or form.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A. If you require all words to be in a document but don't require the words to be consecutive and in the order you specify: The query

```
+big +red
```

matches

```
* the big red fox jumped
* the red big fox jumped
* the big fast red fox jumped
```

but does not match

```
* the small red fox jumped
```

B. If you want to match a phrase (i.e. all words required; the words have to be consecutive and in the order specified) instead: The query

```
+"big red"
```

matches

```
* the big red fox jumped
```

but does not match

```
* the red big fox jumped
* the big fast red fox jumped
* the small red fox jumped
```

Comment: Ok that makes sense.  Marking this as the answer since you gave me examples for consecutive matching as well.  I guess I need to write a string parser to convert user input into a correct lucene query string, that should be interesting.

Comment: sorry to ask after long time. if i want to return data if there the word foudn called Red but big is not there or big is there but red is not there then how the query should look like.

Comment: @Thomas The query syntax supports grouping clauses by parentheses. So, this should work: `(+red -big) (+big -red)`

Comment: how we can add "Contains" query for this like "*+"big red"*"

Answer (score 2):

What do you get when your query is `var query = parser.Parse("+big +abcdefg +test1234");` That should cause the parser to require all terms to be present in matching documents. Another possibility is to construct the query programmatically.

```
BooleanQuery query = new BooleanQuery();
query.add(new BooleanClause(new TermQuery(new Term("field", "big"))), Occur.MUST);
query.add(new BooleanClause(new TermQuery(new Term("field", "abcdefg"))), Occur.MUST);
query.add(new BooleanClause(new TermQuery(new Term("field", "test1234"))), Occur.MUST);
```