# How to do pattern matching in Lucene.Net?

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

I have created a Lucene index which has unique street name as below

```
StreetName
~~~~~~~~~
13th Avenue
13th Street
```

Now if I have a search-string as '1204 13th Avenue TAMPA', how can i create a query that returns me the matching terms from the Lucene index i.e. '13th Avenue'

Comment: Are you saying that given that search string there is nothing being returned from the index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should match what you require.  Providing the words weren't in your ignore list when creating the index.

```
StreetName: ("1204" "13th" "Avenue" "TAMPA")
```

See here for some more details on query syntax http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/2_9_1/queryparsersyntax.html

Related Answer
[How do I perform an AND search in Lucene.net when multiple words are used in a search?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5917653/how-do-i-perform-an-and-search-in-lucene-net-when-multiple-words-are-used-in-a-s)

Comment: I am doing this to parse the street name from the address, so should i create all possible combination of the input search string in sequence i.e. "1204", +"1204 13th", +"1204 13th Avenue", +"1204 13th Avenue TAMPA", +"13th" etc. Then combine them using OR operand and search. Please suggest

Comment: I have altered the search term.  That will perform an or search you will probably be best using ranking/scoring to get a best match at the top of your results.  (On thing though it will only perform an OR search if you didn't change the default operator)

Comment: I believe your query is incorrect, and effectively equivalent to: `StreetName:"1204" DefaultField:"13th" DefaultField:"Avenue" DefaultField:"TAMPA"` (See the last point in [this section](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/2_9_1/queryparsersyntax.html#Fields)).  I think you might be looking for something like:  `Streetname:(1204 13th Avenue TAMPA)` (see [field grouping](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/2_9_1/queryparsersyntax.html#Field%20Grouping))?

Comment: @femtoRgon yes you are correct it's been over a year since using lucene and I put in a common mistake good catch